# What is the easiest way to get all strings that do not start with a character?

Tags: python, string, startswith

I am trying to parse about 20 million lines from a text file and am looking for a way to do some further manipulations on lines that do not start with question marks. I would like a solution that does not use regex matching.  What I would like to do is something like this:

```
for line in x:
    header = line.startswith('?')
if line.startswith() != header:
        DO SOME STUFF HERE
```

I realize the `startswith` method takes one argument, but is there any simple solution to get all lines from a line that DO NOT start with a question mark?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use generator expressions, the best way I think.

```
for line in (line for line in x if not line.startswith('?')):
    DO_STUFF
```

Or your way:

```
for line in x:
    if line.startswith("?"):
        continue
    DO_STUFF
```

Or:

```
for line in x:
    if not line.startswith("?"):
        DO_STUFF
```

It is really up to your programming style. I prefer the first one, but maybe second one seems simplier. But I don't really like third one because of a lot of indentation.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a nice one-liner, which is very close to natural language.

String definition:

```
StringList = [ '__one', '__two', 'three', 'four' ]
```

Code which performs the deed:

```
BetterStringList = [ p for p in StringList if not(p.startswith('__'))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is probably what you're after:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as fh:
  for line in fh:
    if line[0] != '?': # strings can be accessed like lists - they're immutable sequences.
      continue
    # All of the processing here when lines don't start with question marks.
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to utdemir's answer:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse  # just "filterfalse" if using Python 3

for line in ifilterfalse(lambda s: s.startswith('?'), lines):
    # DO STUFF
```

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilterfalse
http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse